# ggplot2: side by side barplot with one bar stacked and the other not

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to create a barplot where for each category, two bars are plotted (side by side): one is for the "total", the other is stacked by subgroups. For example, in the following data frame, 'names' will be shown on x-axis. For each category in 'names', one bar will represent the value of 'total', the other will be a stacked bar representing values from 'aaa', 'bbb' and 'ccc'. I managed to get a 'back-to-back' plot but I don't know how to apply the 'dodge' position to this case to make the bars side-by-side.

```
df = data.frame(names = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=4), 
                num = c(rep(c("aaa","bbb","ccc","total"), 3)), 
                values = c(1,2,3,7,2,2,5,10,3,4,2,9)))
p = ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names))) + 
    geom_bar(data=subset(df,num=="total"), aes(y=values), stat="identity",width=.5) +
    geom_bar(data=subset(df,num!="total"), aes(y=-values,fill=factor(num)), stat="identity",width=.5) 
print(p)
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a figure where the subgroups and total bars are adjacent or, as you describe in what you have so far, back to back?

Comment: I hope to have them adjacent to each other...back-to-back is what I can get for now (without using facets)...sorry about the confusion...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use facets. It seems you cannot stack and dodge at the same time (see related posts below). You can add another factor to your data for the x variable and facet on your names variable to come up with something like this:

Edit: Adjusted width of bars to have bars touching as per comments. See here: [Remove space between bars ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887066/remove-space-between-bars-ggplot2).

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = place, y = values, colour = num, fill = num))
p <- p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = "stack")
p <- p + facet_grid(. ~ names)
p
```

[image]

It looks like you can adjust the margins of the facets to make the ABC groups look closer together if you're interested. For some examples, see these related posts:

[ggplot2 - bar plot with both stack and dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715635/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-both-stack-and-dodge)

[ggplot2 geom_bar position = "dodge" does not dodge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005782/ggplot2-geom-bar-position-dodge-does-not-dodge)

[Plotting a stacked bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592041/plotting-a-stacked-bar-plot)

Edited data with added "place" factor:

```
df <-    structure(list(names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    num = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L), .Label = c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "total"), class = "factor"), 
    values = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 2, 2, 5, 10, 3, 4, 2, 9), position = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("nums", 
    "total"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("names", "num", 
"values", "place"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Good to know this trick, but I do hope the bar for "nums" and "total" are shown as close as possible. If it is impossible to do dodge and stack together, I will definitely use this alternative. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also increase the width of the bars to better fit the figure.
Try this:

```
 p = ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(names)), ) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.75,data=subset(df,num=="total"), aes(y=values), stat="identity",width=.5) +
  geom_bar( width=0.75, data=subset(df,num!="total"), aes(y=-values,fill=factor(num)), stat="identity",width=.5) 
print(p)
```

[image: New plot]

**EDIT:**

I think I misunderstood your question. Do you want the bars within one name to be side by side?

Comment: Yes..I want something like the plot generated by LJW as shown below, but I don't want to use facet..According to him, it seems stack and dodge can't be done together...not sure if you know how to do this..thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there have been changes to the ggplot2 package since these answers were posted. I am using R version 4.0.2 and ggplot2 version 3.3.3. If I follow what you are asking, I believe the `stat='identity'` and the `position=position_dodge()` arguments inside the `geom_bar` function should get after what you desired, at least it did for me.

```
  ggplot(df, aes(names, values, fill=num))+
     geom_bar(stat='identity', position = position_dodge())
```

[image]